# Biological Neural Network Modification to Unlearn Understandings

Tags: neuroscience, neural-network, brain

Lets assume that a person grows up thinking that religion X is true religion. So he builds up a profile in ones head and when notion of religion X appears the neurons that is related are fired, giving sensation of God and related stuff.

Lets us also assume that later in life he learns that religion X was not correct, then does "realization" of this fact happens by modifying old neural networks or a new profile is created for religion X and old profile gets deleted?

In other words do neurons associated with sensation that religion X was true religion "modified" or a new network is created giving a new sensation that religion X was not true religion along!

In my general understanding modification of old network could be challenging assuming that they are surrounded by other neurons associated with other stuff, a certain modification by having more or less neurons would result in borrowing neighboring neurons and wiring them to create a modification or loosing some connections to create a modification, which doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: Are you intending to ask about the religion-specific part of this question, or did you intend that as just an example? There is no plausible way to study the question for that specific example, but you will find experiments that study remapping in much simpler cases, such as when a rodent learns a task a certain way and then the paradigm changes.

Comment: @BryanKrause when you say remapping, this is what I am interested in, so is remapping equates to modifying existing or creating new network? Because the notion of modifying means borrowing neurons or unlinking neuron, which brings the notion that if we borrow neuron from the neighboring network then wont it effect the neighboring network?

Comment: @BryanKrause I am not looking for religion-specific, its just an example.

Comment: @BryanKrause is there a reference to the rodent example that you mentioned.